# How to manage puppet control repo branches?

Tags: git, puppet

We have a control repo `platformX` which has 3 branches: `dev`, `test` and `model`.

The control repo consists of the following files/dirs which get modified each time we introduce a new module:

1. hieradata
2. Puppetfile: points to the module directory
3. site dir: contains the roles & profiles modules invocations

**A simple workflow**

1. Work on module and test locally
2. Push module to remote repo
3. Branch out from `dev` to say `feature_1`  and update the files and directories above
4. Test on a single host with the environment `feature_1`
5. Merge `feature_1` with `dev`

**Problems Faced**

Now I have the `dev` branch with the new module. Whats the best way to update `test` and `model`? Keep in mind that I cannot merge `dev` with `test` and then `test` with `model` because:

1. There maybe changes in `dev` that is not ready to be applied in `test` or `model`yet
2. I could inadvertently introduce something I shouldn't because I initially branched from `dev`.

I could branch from `test`, update heiradata, Puppetfile and roles & profiles to introduce the changes to `test` but this seems cumbersome because I have to repeat this again for `model` which inevitably can lead to human errors.

I'm sure others have faced this problem and have a sound solution - care to share your thoughts?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `test` tracks `model` and `dev` tracks `test`? It wouldn't make much sense to have changes in prod that are not in test/dev, right? In which case you should always just branch off `model` (production). Merge feature branches to `dev`, then later merge the feature branch to `test` and finally merge it directly to `model`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You do have a point about branching from a an environment 'closest to production'. The previous concerns were around what changes will get introduced when we merge to `dev` and `test`. Will take closer look at if this is viable and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: @FelixFrank: So a question that arose from your suggested implementation is a scenario where we use `hieradata` to specify versions of software we want installed and this can be different from environment to environment. In the event we branch from `model` which say has `x:1` in (hieradata) however when we merge this `feature` branch with `dev` I'd imagine we'll have merge conflicts if `x:2` (which most likely will). Considering there might be multiple key/value property pairs and not to mention in multiple files, this might turn out to be a tedious activity everytime we merge to environments.

Comment: Yes, you're bound to experience merge pains when your dev/test branches are permanently different from production. No way around that that I can see, short of careful tailoring the git repo granularity. But then you might end up with submodules, which is a whole other world of pain.

Comment: According to my research the r10k developers want us to use simple feature branching (aka [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/)), using `production` as your main branch. Hence, rename `master` to `production` to start with, then always branch off feature branches from `production`, test them, and merge or rebase the changes into `production` again. -- Avoid several long-living branches, stick to a single `production` branch and use short-lived feature branches.